# How Can I Change One Column With No Patterns to Clearly Defined Rows and Columns?

Tags: mysql, excel, data-cleaning

Looking for any tricks using SQL or Excel to clean up a ~100k record table that has no clear pattern. The data generally looks like this all blocked together in separate rows but the same column:

```
JENNIFER SMITH
Accountant - Senior
Day Shift
jsmith@mail.com

AMBER Jones
Professional
Pro Status

amberj@mail.com

Abby Stone
Receptionist
Analytics
123 Main St
123-456-7890
abby@mail.com

REBECCA MILLER
Media
Building 2
millerr@mail.com
Sarah M Myers
Executive
BRADBURY SCHOOL
456 Main St
```

The big problem is that some records have three sets of additional data beneath it and some records have five -- maybe they have an email and/or phone number maybe they don't, some have lines after the record some don't, etc.

I'm looking for ideas either using code or formulas to attempt to clean this up to look like below without going through every line manually:

```
Name            Job                 Info        Email          Phone           Address
JENNIFER SMITH  Accountant - Senior Day Shift   jsmith@mail.com     
AMBER Jones     Professional        Pro Status  amberj@mail.com     
Abby Stone      Receptionist        Analytics   abby@mail.com  123-456-7890    123 Main St
REBECCA MILLER  Media               Building 2  millerr@mail.com        
Sarah M Myers   Executive           BRADBURY SCHOOL                            456 Main St
```

Hoping people might have ideas using scenarios they've had to use in the past on really messy datasets that come in like this. If it's in Excel, it could be some combination of using SEARCH() or LEN() to try and identify when each record's data is over.

I know it's not the most pointed question -- but if anybody has any tips it'd really help me out. It also doesn't have to end up being perfect -- if it ends up looking mildly like above, I'll be able to clean it manually from that point on, just not from the start.

Any help using any method would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's not looking good for you.  Sorry...

Comment: Where does the data come from. How can the system that produces the data be so devoid of intelligence?

Comment: @Strawberry    No idea -- this is just an example of what I got sent. It's amazingly horrible.

Comment: Can you speak to/maim the sender?

Comment: Thanks for the notes, everyone! Sounds like it's a manual job.

Comment: On the basis of the information provided so far yes - although it seems impossible that someone would be stupid enough to build a database of 100000 records without using, well, a database.

Comment: That said, it may be possible to automate some parts of the problem. For instance, those records that have email addresses always appear to have that as the last row of the record.

Comment: @Strawberry    Right, that's what I was thinking something like -- if the email is always the last row (if they have an email), I could use SEARCH("@",A2) or something to find where theres an email to denote the end of that record. But what would I do from there to get it to look normal?

Comment: Are you sure that the source file - whatever generates this output - has no more intelligence within it?

Comment: @Strawberry    I think it's less of a database and more of auto-converted PDFs or something. 99% sure I'd either have to figure something out like this or just try and get people to help move it manually.

Comment: In that case, unfortunately, I think Thomas may be right.

Answer (score 0):

You would spend more time jerking around with this with code than it would be worth.  Such badly formatted data can't possibly be accurate.  How on earth would you know Jennifer Smith still uses the email address indicated or has the job listed?  If you are somehow forced to work on this data then you would be better off paying a human to key it in.  That shouldn't take more than a week and you can probably get someone to do it for a few hundred bucks.  Even so, that data is certainly crap so I can't see the point in bothering.